# Sommer Package: mmer versus MEMMA

Tags: r, genetics

Good day,  I am performing genomic prediction (GBLUP) in tetraploid species.  I started using sommer last year before the changes.  Back then you could use the **mmer** function with the **ZETA** argument to specify the covariance of the random term. Now there is the specification with the **random~ vs(...)**

I compared this to the **MEMMA** function which utilises the **ZETA** argument, and as I understand it is used internally in mmer. For some reason however I am getting different answers,  eg

```
    library(devtools)
    install_github("covaruber/sommer")
    library(sommer)
     install.packages("AGHmatrix")
    library(AGHmatrix) 



    data(DT_polyploid)
     # ####=========================================####
     # ####### convert markers to numeric format
     # ####=========================================####
      numo <- atcg1234(data=GT, ploidy=4);

     # ###=========================================####
     # ###### plants with both genotypes and phenotypes
     # ###=========================================####
      common <- intersect(DT$Name,rownames(numo$M))
     #
     # ###=========================================####
     # ### get the markers and phenotypes for such inds
     # ###=========================================####
     marks <- numo$M[common,]; marks[1:5,1:5]
      DT2 <- DT[match(common,DT$Name),];

     # ###=========================================#### 

     G.A <- Gmatrix(marks, method="VanRaden", ploidy=4, missingValue=NA, impute.method = TRUE)
     G.D <- Gmatrix(marks, method="Endelman", ploidy=4, missingValue=NA, impute.method = TRUE)    

     T.pheno <- DT2[,c(1,9)]
     T.pheno$Name <- as.factor(T.pheno$Name)
     T.pheno$Name2 <- T.pheno$Name

    set.seed(1892) 
    rrn <- sample(1:187, 50, replace = F)
    T.pheno$sucrose[rrn] <- NA

    ans.A <-  mmer(sucrose ~ 1,
                   random=~vs(Name, Gu=G.A),
                   rcov = ~units,
                   data=T.pheno)


    cor(ans.A$U$`u:Name`$sucrose[which(is.na(T.pheno$sucrose))], 
        DT2$sucrose[which(is.na(T.pheno$sucrose))], use = "pairwise")
```

> [1] 0.2205831

Then applying the same analysis using MEMMA

```
Z1 <- diag(length(T.pheno$sucrose))
Z2 <- diag(length(T.pheno$sucrose))

ETA.A <- list(list(Z=Z1, K=G.A) )
ETA.AD <- list(list(Z=Z1, K=G.A), list(Z=Z2, K=G.D) )


ans.A <- MEMMA(Y=T.pheno$sucrose, ZETA=ETA.A)

cor(ans.A$fitted.y[which(is.na(T.pheno$sucrose))], 
    DT2$sucrose[which(is.na(T.pheno$sucrose))], use = "pairwise")
```

> [1] 0.2778689

Why is there a difference?  For adding dominance and epistasis matrices, I find the formulation in MEMMA easier and less prone to errors, and of course I am encouraged by the higher prediction accuracies. Secondly, the MEMMA function provides fitted values that are on the same scale and therefore comparable to the observed values. However MEMMA is quite slow... and still there should be an explanation for the difference in accuracy.  Below is the code and results for both mmer and MEMMA when including dominance.

```
ans.AD <-  mmer(sucrose ~ 1,
                random= ~ vs(Name, Gu=G.A) + vs(Name2, Gu=G.D),
                rcov = ~ units,
                data=T.pheno)

cor(ans.AD$U$`u:Name`$sucrose[which(is.na(T.pheno$sucrose))], 
    DT2$sucrose[which(is.na(T.pheno$sucrose))], use = "pairwise")


ans.AD <- MEMMA(Y=T.pheno$sucrose, ZETA=ETA.AD)

cor(ans.AD$fitted.y[which(is.na(T.pheno$sucrose))], 
    DT2$sucrose[which(is.na(T.pheno$sucrose))], use = "pairwise")
```

> [1] 0.2357571 (mmer with dominance)
>
> [1] 0.2785493 (MEMMA with dominance)

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why the MEMMA function is not part of the mmer function but only put available as an aside function are:

1) variance components are not estimated properly when you move to more than one random effect other than the error

2) Inability to use special covariance structures in the residuals (again in the same problem of more than 1 vc)

3) Beside the simplest scenario this algorithm is terrible slow to estimate the VC.

Now, the reason why the Newton-Raphson (NR), and Average-Information (AI) (which are the only methods available in the mmer() function) give different results than MEMMA must be related to fact that for more than one vc the REML estimates of MEMMA usually go outside the parameter space. This algorithm was originally designed for a single vc beside the vc for the error. I would actually say that NR and AI are most likely giving you the right vc values.

In addition, just because one value gives better results for MEMMA doesn't mean that across let say 200 iterations this will be true. I would perform some cross validation to see if this holds. And even if it holds, the NR/AI are less prone to go outside the parameter space giving you the correct values.

About the fitted values slot. MEMMA still returns fitted values as

y.hat = Xb + Zu

whereas the results from the mmer() function the fitted values slot are of the form:

y.hat= Xb

if you want to for predictions in the original scale you have to construct them yourself by building Xb and Zu, or you can use the predict() function available.

Also to show you how basing which algorithm to use based on this accuracy can be very subjective, you can try for the same example but now specify in the mmer() function the argument na.method.Y = "include" and see how the PA goes up to 0.27. Lesson, small changes in PA are not that relevant from my perspective. Paper showing increases of PA of 5 units (0.05) are from my perspective in the wrong path, but just my humble opinion.

I hope this helps.

Cheers,
Eduardo